# Averaging quadrants in a matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to average a quadrant of 4 elements in a `24X16 matrix`.  The matrix is separated in to thirds `(3-8X16s)` and has repeating quadrants in each section, that are designated lo mid and high (these are experimental conditions).

My question is two fold:
1) I am attempting to unlist this selection of 4 to calculate the mean, then repeat the process on the next selection of 4 until I'm finished with that third. Concatenating all these values under a name lo_siRNA_average returns an `"unexpected symbol"` error:

```
lo_siRNA_average <- c(mean(unlist(expData[1:2,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[3:4,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[5:6,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[7:8,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[9:10,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[11:12,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[13:14,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[15:16,1:2])) mean(unlist(expData[1:2,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[3:4,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[5:6,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[7:8,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[9:10,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[11:12,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[13:14,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[15:16,3:4])), mean(unlist(expData[1:2,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[3:4,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[5:6,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[7:8,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[9:10,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[11:12,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[13:14,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[15:16,5:6])), mean(unlist(expData[1:2,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[3:4,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[5:6,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[7:8,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[9:10,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[11:12,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[13:14,7:8])), mean(unlist(expData[15:16,7:8])))
Error: unexpected symbol in "(expData[1:2,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[3:4,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[5:6,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[7:8,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[9:10,1:2])), mean(unlist(expData[11:12,1:2])), mean(unl"
```

2) Is there way to automate the matrix locations as a loop so its not as long?

Comment: "unexpected symbol" just means that you have a simple syntax error in there somewhere. A missing or extra parenthesis, a misplaced or missing comma, etc. And it's not surprising that you'd accidentally type something wrong in an expression like that.

Comment: As for your second question, I would recommend reshaping the data then using `apply()`

Answer (score 1):

As commented above: reshape your matrix and use apply/aggregate.

```
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1)
expData <- matrix(rnorm(24*16), ncol = 16)

df <- melt(expData)
df$rowInd <- rep(1:8, each = 3)
df$colInd <- rep(1:8, each = 48)

res <- aggregate(value ~ rowInd + colInd, df, mean)

# Check if this is what you want:
aggregate(value ~ rowInd + colInd, df, mean)[1,"value"] == mean(expData[1:3, 1:2])
```